# FileSecurity on CD-R files/folders using C#

Tags: c#

How to Add Security or change the owner of files inside the CD-R using C#? is this possible.

I use [this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity.aspx) from msdn.

It works ok, but when I change the path/file from `D:\folders\myfiles.txt` which is the CD-R.
it says unauthorized to perform action.

Comment: afaik, once a CD-R is written to, it can never be changed. Thus you can't change the owner of the file.

Comment: Thanks jb, just as I thought, this is not possible. Is there any other way to deny user from viewing/browsing files on CD-R?

Comment: If you are the one creating the disc, I suppose you could hide the files which would stop the average joe user. If that isn't good enough, maybe you could zip the files and password protect it?

Comment: Do you have any control over the files on the CD-R before they are written?  If so even though you can't prevent the user from seeing the files themselves you could encrypt them so that the user can't see the contents easily.

Comment: yes we have control of the files, I guess hiding the files is the solution. I used the cd burner from codeproject, I just need to edit this and add the hide files features just like in Nero burner. Thanks jb and Mike for big help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CD-R means **CD Write-Once** disk. You cannot modify any data in the disk once it was written. If you want to set the file security, you need to modify the file metadata, stored with the file on the disk. Therefore, it will raise this error.

Comment: Thanks Edward, appreciate this one.